# Click event works under navigation, fails under toolbar

Tags: swift

If I add button to my Navigation, the click event works perfectly, however, my ToolBar is not working.

```
var tool = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 420, self.view.frame.size.width, 60))
var barBtnDelete = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Trash,
                                   target: self,
                                   action:"Delete:")
var barBtnSlideShow = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Play,
                                      target: self,
                                      action: ("SlideShow"))
var arraybarbutton = [barBtnSlideShow,barBtnDelete];
tool.setItems(arraybarbutton, animated: true)
view.addSubview(tool)
```

Neither click event fires. I haven't been able to find a solution

Both Click Event is not working..and my slideshow Event don't have any parameter

Comment: Which click event is not working ?

Comment: your colon is missing there ("SlideShow:")) if your selector Have any Parameter have  any  argument  then we have to put semicolon

Comment: Both Click Event is not working..and my slideshow Event don't have any parameter so i am not put it colon over there...

Comment: btu I Do same thing, and result is  my toolbaar delete button is working...

Comment: I've edited to improve formatting and grammar. Please check I haven't changed your meaning

Comment: Does your class have `func Delete(sender: AnyObject)` and `func Slideshow(sender: AnyObject)` functions?